# List view in mainactivity not scrollable after adding Drawable widget

Tags: android, listview

MainActivity.xml here 
See the List view .. earlier this was scrollable before adding the Drawer widget, But now its not working . what am i doing wrong here.Please help"
MainActivity.xml here 
See the List view .. earlier this was scrollable before adding the Drawer widget, But now its not working . what am i doing wrong here.Please help"
MainActivity.xml here 
See the List view .. earlier this was scrollable before adding the Drawer widget, But now its not working . what am i doing wrong here.Please help"
MainActivity.xml here 
See the List view .. earlier this was scrollable before adding the Drawer widget, But now its not working . what am i doing wrong here.Please help"
MainActivity.xml here 
See the List view .. earlier this was scrollable before adding the Drawer widget, But now its not working . what am i doing wrong here.Please help"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.raywenderlich.alltherecipes.MainActivity">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">
  </ListView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_fullscreen_ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_fullscreen_ad"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <!-- Profile Box -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profileBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                android:padding="8dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatar"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rishabh"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/desc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="View Profile"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/navList"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is your xml

Comment: Updated the xml as well

Comment: <ListView
      android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">
  </ListView>   this is my main list view -- where i list out items

Comment: then added android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> for sidebar.. after this my main list view scrolling is not working

Comment: Any one knows why this is happening ?

Comment: @Dinesh Saini - Any hope?

Comment: Are you trying to use a "Drawable" or the Navigation Drawer?

Comment: Navigation Drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your **ListView** inside the **DrawerLayout**.
Like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_fullscreen_ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ListView>


        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <!-- Profile Box -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profileBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                android:padding="8dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatar"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rishabh"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/desc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="View Profile"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/navList"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works for me.